# Microsoft Office Compatible-Software

Tags: linux, office

I require a Linux document system compatible with Microsoft Office (`doc` and `docx` for example).

Currently testing [Kingsoft](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/), [Free Office](http://www.freeoffice.com/en/) and [Star Office](http://www.staroffice.org/). All seem to have the same functionality.

Requirements:

- Run natively on Linux, i.e. can install package via `sud apt-get install`
- Supports formatting of Office Suite (`doc`, `docx` etc.)
- Free, "Gratis" software

Comment: Which version of [MSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Versions) you are looking the alternative to be compatible with? Certain versions of MSO are not even compatible with each other. Also, why [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) is not listed?

Comment: HI im using libre office and kingsoft office but I dont get full compatibility when pass word offfice document from windows  to linux and viceversa this change the layout

Comment: Im looking the best compatible tool with version 2003, 2010 to up

Comment: I see freeoffice look fine but I dont use for much time

Comment: MSO versions 2003 and 2010 are not fully compatible. When it comes to complex formatting, even modern MSO versions might behave differently, e.g. in a way they position a picture when it's not anchored properly. If you don't really care or you are working with rather primitive documents, virtually any of the office suits will do. I personally use LibreOffice everywhere (W/L) for the past few years, it is good enough for me.

Comment: yes I like libreoffice too but Im looking an alternate version for another person who uses windows

Comment: Well, if this person prefers the suit that looks and feels like a modern Microsoft Office, and doesn't care about privacy and opensource, then [WPS Office](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/) you listed first is a great solution.

Comment: I have also seen that libreoffice fails but I have read in some blogs that are solving some problems recently also the most similar to office of this three I think it is freeoffice on the other hand I could say that kde for example kalligra has good perfomance and good design but does not support All formats

Comment: I think kde has a lot of potential

Comment: For example I have seen a very similar paint clone called kolourpaint(kde)

Comment: libreoffice is very good but this is slow compare with office and kalligra

Comment: the principal problem for a windows user is not the design of the office tool is the compatibility with the format  of document

Comment: the second problem could be the perfomance

Comment: LibreOffice or OpenOffice.

Comment: [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: I have no idea about compatibility but a supposedly popular suite is Polaris Office.  Should be easy to see if it meets you needs from their own website: https://www.polarisoffice.com/en/